# Calling HTTPS-webservice (TLS) from IIS fails occasionally

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, https, crm

I want to call a simple webservice from a CRM 2013 plugin which is hosted on IIS 8. The webservice is accessible via HTTPS with TLS encryption. I try to access the service from C# with the System.Net.WebClient. Everything works fine as long as the code which accesses the service is executed on the console (same server as IIS is installed). If executed from the CRM Plugin a WebException occurs from time to time. So sometimes it works 10 times in a row, sometimes every second call fails. The WebException says:

*`"Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel".`*

I tried to log the connection in WireShark which shows the following error:

*`"Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Access Denied)"`*

I have absolutely no idea, what's the reason for this strange behaviour. Especially why it works sometimes and sometimes not is not really clear to me.
Anybody who could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Using WireShark I found out that the client seems to send a "Session Ticket" sometimes. Then the server answers with "Access denied". If the client doesn't send this session ticket, everything works fine. But why does the client send this session ticket and where does is get the ticket from?

Comment: Maybe a specific part of your c# code is asking for a "handShake" that as not been implemented on the server side : https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tlsssl-and-.net-framework-4.0/